# Need Methodology to replicate a panel with button and shifting other buttons in a same time

Tags: c#, .net, button, panel

Here is my form [image: Here is my form]

If I click on "Add" on the first panel I want to create "Strategy1_2" just below the first and shift all others panels down. 
If I click again I want to create Strategy1_3 (...)

I know how to create a button but not how to duplicate a entire panel. 
Here is my code for a button is it far from this procedure ?

```
private void addstrat1_i_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel3strat.Width += 200;
    Button addstrat1_2 = new Button();
    addstrat3_2.Size = new Size(210, 41);
    addstrat1_2.Location = new Point(31,89);
    addstrat1_2.Visible = true;
    panel1strat.Controls.Add(addstrat3_2);

}
```

Comment: by the way, learning WPF may be painful, but really worth it for this task

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be that you create a UserControl for your strategy panel. You can then insert the UserControls to a FlowLayoutPanel. This will resolve your issue with placing controls exactly and to create a copy of some panels.

Be aware that you can run out of resources (e.g. windows handles) when adding to much controls on your form. This can be solved by only showing a certain amount of controls and shifting the data through this "fixed" controls while scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend having two methods: `CreatePanelBlock()` that will issue a `UserControl` that you'll add to your container, and `BindPanelWithData(...)` that will setup the dependencies.

Remember, you may make your panel as a custom control.